# paypal auto return with manual return button cause bug in application

Tags: grails, paypal

I am using paypal with my Grails 2.1.1 version. After successful processing of payment in paypal, showing a success page configured auto return and also a manual Return button to the same url. If user does not click on the return button, then everything is fine. But if user clicks on the Return button, then the same request comes twice to my action (auto return also send the same request).
Is it possible to filter this duplicate request to do nothing on controller's action as it is already progressing for manual return click request or set paypal for not sending the Auto return request for that payment if user click the manual Return button.?
Or any better way to handle this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Payment Data Transfer to get the transaction Id.

From the docs at: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer

**When a customer pays you, PayPal sends the transaction ID of the payment to you by appending the transaction ID to a URL you specify in your account Profile. This information is sent via a HTTP GET as this name/value pair:tx=transactionID**

Then you can check if transactionID is already processed or not.

Also, you may do complete payment validation by sending these parameters back to paypal as described in link above.

Comment: Thanks. I have already implemented it. My problem is another. On success page, I have a Return button as well Auto return enable with return url. If user wait for auto return then everything is fine (I validated the payment based on return trnxID and update the Payment as COMPLETED based on success). But if user click Manual Return button, then same request comes to the server twice within seconds. How can i stop auto return if user click the return button.?

Comment: Paypal does not seem to handle duplicate conditions. From paypal docs: "It is possible for the customer to refresh the page. So if you are inserting records to a database, you must check for duplicates". So you may insert records into db in first request and if you get more requests with same txId and payment status(you should check in db, if that txId is already processed or not), you can ignore that for further processing/display back to user.